# How to use some ng-view in template?

Tags: angularjs

I have some `ng-view` in my template. One is uses for preloader, another for routing.

Problem is that routing taked all `ng-view` in template. How to use some `ng-view` in template seperated?

Comment: ngRoute uses the same `<ng-view>` for all routes. need better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: You can't use multiple ngView directives. If you need it consider UIRouter.

Comment: I need to open page with specifed URL, and after set data in controller

Comment: suggest you go through routing section of tutorial in angular docs site

Comment: As you might have noticed Angular doesn't work well with multiple `ng-view`'s. Use `ng-include` instead in your template.